# Ionic XMLHttpRequest FormData empty after append file

Tags: http, post, ionic2, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I'm trying to send a file with a post with ionic 2

In order to ask for the file, i use an invisible input type file

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;" #file id="fileUpoload"  style="display: none">
```

The button call the function in this way:

```
(click)="onFileUpoloadButtonPressed(file)"
```

And this is the function called:

```
onFileUpoloadButtonPressed(element){
document.getElementById("fileUpoload").onchange = function(e : any){

  let file = {
    name: e.srcElement.files[0].name,
    file: e.srcElement.files[0],
  };



  //I get the id of the user since i have to perform an edit call to my api
  this.storage.get("userLogged").then((value) => {

    setTimeout(function(){
      this.postChangeAvatar(this, parseInt(value.data.utenti_id), file,
        function (ext, result){ //Success callback
          console.log(result);

        },
        function(ext, error){   //Error callback
          console.log(error);
          alert(error);
        }
      )
    }, 100)

  })

}
element.click();
```

}

This is the postChangeAvatar function that perform the post request:

```
postChangeAvatar(ext, id, file, successCallback, errorCallback){
let formData : any = new FormData();
let xhr : any = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log(id);
console.log(file); //File is successfully get

formData.append('user_photo', file.file, file.name);


for (var pair of formData.entries()) { //This is showing nothing
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
}

xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4){
    if (xhr.status == 200){
      successCallback(ext, xhr.response);
    }
    else {
      errorCallback(ext, xhr.response);
    }
  }
}
xhr.open('POST', "http://xxxxxxxxxx/api/edit/utenti/" + id, true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

}

The post is performed but the formData remains empty after append the file, trying to print the formdata with the for each doesn't show anything, so the only thing wrong is the formData being empty when post is performed

As you can see i tried to encapsulate the entire request in a setTimeout to be sure the file is obtained, the file is in there but is not appendend in the formData

From the server i can see the body of the request empty
I tried this method in another project and in there was successfully working so i'm a bit surprised seeing this not working

If i'm not able to get this working maybe there's another way to post selected files with ionic 2?

Comment: Have u solve this prob?

Comment: @keshav unfortunately no, i have to use the base64 at least

Answer (score 0):

Here is working piece of code (base64 file upload). Try setting header. Add `enctype` to `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` to prevent CORS.

```
 insertPost(data): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers({ "enctype": "multipart/form-data" });
    data.userId = this.globalProvider.userId;
    var form_data = new FormData();
    for (var key in data) {
      form_data.append(key, data[key]);
    }
    return this.http.post(`${baseURL}insertPost`, form_data, { headers: headers })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me, my form data remains empty after appended the file

Comment: Why don't you use base64? Use camera plugin for taking picture or selecting it from gallery. By doing this you can optimize (MBs to KBs), resize, crop  image that will make your app faster.

Comment: I can't use base64 since i can't edit server code, and the server accepts only file taken by input, so i need to send it in this way